# What's the easiest way to transfer photos from Google Photos to iCloud Photos?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, google, google-photos

I have more than 5 000 photos stored on Google Photos and I'd like to know what's the easiest way to move them on iCloud photos. Since the free storage ends on June I want to move everything on iCloud.

Here's what I've tried :

- Selecting all of them on the Google Photos app and downloading them, but it randomly skips some pictures, and it stops after some hours of download. Since it downloads them in a random order I have to delete them all and start over.
- Downloading them from Google Takeout and uploading them from icloud.com on a PC, but it only accepts JPEG files, so most of the pictures are not uploaded (the file format is .HEIC) and videos are skipped.

I have no other idea on how to do this, I hope anyone can help!

Answer (score 1):

Your second idea seems like it's very close to working. But I think the issue is that icloud.com is just not a 'first class' interface to icloud photos. Instead try:

1. Download the photos to your mac from Google using [Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/)
2. Enable iCloud Photos on Apple Photos on your Mac

   [image: The Apple Photos iCloud Setting Page]
3. Add the photos to Apple Photos on your Mac, and wait for them to be uploaded to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the photos from Google to your PC and then upload them to icloud.com

Comment: I’ve tried that too, but Google gives us two files (photo + video) so I loose Live Photos :/

Answer (score -1):

I have been attempting to do the very same thing for at least two weeks now.

I used Google Takeout and successfully imported all the files using the Photos application (which I sync to iCloud). I'd recommend this route.

My sticking point is that Apple's facial recognition is absolute trash. After two weeks of using both my 2017 i7 MBP and my iPhone 11 Pro Max, it still hasn't identified the majority of faces even after being tagged.

Comment: I’ve tried with Google Takeout but Live Photos are deleted and it just keeps PNG/JPEG files :/

Comment: I don't know if Live Photos are supported. I usually turn that function off myself. I'm just really disappointed in the lack of reliable functionality and vague work-around hacks that people have to implement for each successive iteration of MacOS or the Photos application. Apple is supposed to "just work" and it doesn't. I'll put my money where my mouth is and gladly leave their ecosystem for one that does work.

Answer (score -1):

Download all the photos from Google Takeout and import all the photos (should be in a folder) and upload them to iCloud Photos on the web, or using a Mac, into the Apple Photos app.

Comment: That answer has already been given.